# Styling button elements - adding text offset on :active

Tags: css, button

I want the text of my `<button>` elements to slightly move down/right when the button is in the `:active` state. I thought I could do that by modifying the internal `padding` of the buttons such that it continues to sum to the same.

My HTML:

```
<button>Hello</button><button>Goodbye</button>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
button {
    border: 1px solid #9f9b9a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url("button.png") repeat-x;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em;
    cursor: default;
}

button:hover {
    border-color: black;
    background-position: left -5px;
}

button:active {
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0 0.6em;
}
```

Finally, here's my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nQFHt/

I'd have thought that by keeping the internal padding sum to `0.2em` vertically and `1em` horizontally that the state of the button would affect the layout of the page at all, but when I mouse-down on `Hello` the `Goodbye` button moves around.

Is there a better way to get the effect I want?

Pics:

[image]

Comment: I can’t see any moving when I test your fiddle in Firefoy or Opera - but it might occur depending on multiple factors like font-size etc. Since you are using em fractions, different rounding might occur when these em values are translated into pixels – so what you _think_ makes the same sum does not in reality. If you can’t use pixel values, then you might need to find another technique.

Comment: Rounding doesn't explain why mousedown on one button causes the other to move.

Comment: @CBroe it repros for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE10. I've updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @MichałRybak: Of course it does, if the _sum_ of the rounded padding values applied on hover is different from the one in the buttons original state – different padding == different element dimensions.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, but there is no *visible* difference in dimensions of buttons (i.e. the border dimensions stay the same), so I assumed (wrong, perhaps) that it stays the same for clicked element. Therefore it shouldn't affect the other one.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm experiencing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could fix the `vertical-align` or `line-height` with `padding` to not modify sizes of button.

```css
 button {
     border: 1px solid #9f9b9a;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: url("button.png") repeat-x;
     font-size: inherit;
     padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em;
     cursor: default;
     vertical-align:top;
 }
 button:hover {
     border-color: black;
     background-position: left -5px;
 }
 button:active {
     line-height:0.7em;
    padding: 0.6em 0.2em 0.1em 0.8em;
 }
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
<button>Goodbye</button>
```

Not too sure of what you look for.

button should move or only the text or something else ?

Comment: Only the text should move. Not sure why but `vertical-align: top` is what fixed it for me.

Comment: @Mark do you  mean this answered the question ?

Comment: I'm not the question-asker, but I put the bounty on because I had the same problem. +100 to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

As for the moving of the buttons, the problem should be, that with changing the padding of one of your buttons you also change its size. Thats why the button next to it is also moving.

A solution would be to insert a `<br />` after each button. As a result the two buttons wouldn't be displayed next to each other.
You should be fine by wrapping an element like a list around your buttons and adding a float:left to the `<li>`'s.

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><button>Hello</button></li>
   <li><button>Goodbye</button></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
button {
    border: 1px solid #9f9b9a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url("button.png") repeat-x;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em;
    cursor: default;
}
button:hover {
    border-color: black;
    background-position: left -5px;
}

button:active {
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0 0.6em;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

I added a jsFiddle for your http://jsfiddle.net/nQFHt/1/

Comment: you can simply put `<br />` between buttons and it will work, too... if the buttons are not next to each other, they behave correctly.

Comment: @MichalRyback I agree with you. Had it in the text, problem was, i forgot to make a code block around it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
button {
    float: left;
}
```

With block elements this issue seems to be fixed.

EDIT: 
After digging a bit, your problem is clear to me. Vertical padding simply doesn't work this way with inline elements.
Take a look at [this article](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/).

Comment: `float:left` is triggering the same properties as `display:block` except `width:100%`.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `<a>` links in place of buttons and style them, since you have a better control over them and many options.

Here is my example:
The HTML:

```
<a href="#"><span>click ME</span></a>
<a href="#"><span>click ME too</span></a>
```

And the CSS:

```
a{
    border: 1px solid #9f9b9a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url("button.png") repeat-x;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{        
    border-color: black;
    background-position: left -5px;
}
a:active div{
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
}
```

Here is my jsFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4wznS/)

Comment: Using `<a>` isn't an option because these buttons are also used for `<form>` submission, as `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: So in your case just replace <a> tags with buttons.